# Creating a separate project for themes and layouts

Tags: liferay, setup-project

Is it possible to create a liferay portal project containing only the theme and the layout ?

The idea is to generate from that project the war file that will be deployed in the portal.

Thank you,

Regards.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're trying to do. I'm guessing by your terminology you're using the Liferay Developer Studio or the Liferay IDE Eclipse plugin?

Comment: @Jonny : Thanks for your answer. Well, What i'm trying to do is to externalize the theme so that I can compile and the deploy the relative "war" file.

Answer (score 0):

A Liferay theme and a Liferay layout would normally be deployed separately (so they can also be re-deployed, upgraded, and removed separately).

Please elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?